# Simplest Shaka Player is not Working

Tags: javascript, html, webm, video-player, shaka

All I want is for my shaka-player to work. I've listed all the files in my Movie Directory. My manifest file (.mpd) is made up of 5 different webm video stream files located in the same directory (I realize the audio isn't there, that is not important in this scenario).

I pretty much followed the tutorial from the website:

https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-welcome.html

I'm not sure why this doesn't work. Can someone help out?

Movie Directory:

```
Movie_WebM.html  
shaka-player.compiled.js  
Movie.js  
Movie_Manifest.mpd              
Movie_160x90_250k.webm                           
Movie_320x180_500k.webm  
Movie_640x360_1000k.webm  
Movie_640x360_750k.webm     
Movie_1280x720_500k.webm
```

Movie_WebM.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="shaka-player.compiled.js"></script>
    <script src="Movie.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="video"
           width="640"
           poster="//shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/assets/poster.jpg"
           controls></video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Movie.js:

```
var manifestUri = 'Movie_Manifest.mpd';

function initApp() {
  shaka.log.setLevel(shaka.log.Level.V1);
  // Install built-in polyfills to patch browser incompatibilities.
  shaka.polyfill.installAll();

  // Check to see if the browser supports the basic APIs Shaka needs.
  if (shaka.Player.isBrowserSupported()) {
    // Everything looks good!
    initPlayer();
  } else {
    // This browser does not have the minimum set of APIs we need.
    console.error('Browser not supported!');
  }
}

function initPlayer() {
  // Create a Player instance.
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var player = new shaka.Player(video);

  // Attach player to the window to make it easy to access in the JS console.
  window.player = player;

  // Listen for error events.
  player.addEventListener('error', onErrorEvent);

  // Try to load a manifest.
  // This is an asynchronous process.
  player.load(manifestUri).then(function() {
    // This runs if the asynchronous load is successful.
    console.log('The video has now been loaded!');
  }).catch(onError);  // onError is executed if the asynchronous load fails.
}

function onErrorEvent(event) {
  // Extract the shaka.util.Error object from the event.
  onError(event.detail);
}

function onError(error) {
  // Log the error.
  console.error('Error code', error.code, 'object', error);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run in on localhost. You can use Python SimpleHTTPServer:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

and open

```
localhost:8000/{MOVIE_DIR}/Movie_WebM.html
```

> EME requires a secure URL to use. This means you have to use https or be on localhost. Currently only Chrome enforces it, but other browsers will in the future. Also, because of mixed content requirements, if your site is using https, then your manifest and every segment will also need to use https too. - https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-drm-config.html